# PHP/MySQL - If no rows of a certain type available, load a place holder

Tags: php, mysql

So I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM cars {$statement} AND deleted = 'no' AND carID NOT IN (SELECT carID FROM reservations WHERE startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."') GROUP BY model
```

It basically checks the reservations table and then if there are reservations, it gets those carIDs and excludes them from the loop.

This is cool, so as there may be three dodge vipers and 2 are booked out it will only display the last one, and it will only display one at a time anyway because I group the results by model.

All that is good, however when it runs out of entries, so all the cars are booked out, the car does not appear in the list of cars. (As i clear from the query).

I would like a way to say if no rows of a certain car model are in the results, to display a placeholder, that says something like 'UNAVAILABLE'.

Is this possible at all? Its mainly so users can see the company owns that car, but knows its not available on that date.

Comment: You need to LEFT JOIN your cars table with booking table .

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You should probably handle this in the PHP, checking the number of rows returned and replacing the 0 with "UNAVAILABLE".</strike>

Based on TO comment:

In this case you want to look at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case.html

This would need to go into the SELECT list like

```
SELECT
CASE car_count WHEN 0 THEN 'UNAVAILABLE'
WHERE ...
```

Comment: It won't return 0 rows though, just 0 rows of a certain model of car, so It would have to be something like if 0 rows are returned of model=viper then display this, but then that isn't going to work if they add new models in the future.

Comment: Please check using function mysql_num_rows() it will return the number of rows of a result.

Comment: @Praveenkalal I'm afraid you didn't get the question.

Answer (score 0):

Without seen some of your data, its hard to give you a query, but if you move your subquery to your select expression, you could return the count available (which would be 0 when they are all reserved).  Then when you display your data, you could then check if the count is 0, and display your unavailable message.

**Edit:**

Given the table cars:

```
+----+----------+
| id | model    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | viper    |
|  2 | explorer |
|  3 | viper    |
|  4 | explorer |
+----+----------+
```

and the table reservations:

```
+-------+------------+
| carid | date       |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | 2013-03-07 |
|     3 | 2013-03-07 |
+-------+------------+
```

A query similar to yours above will return:

```
+----+----------+
| id | model    |
+----+----------+
|  2 | explorer |
+----+----------+
```

If you change it to something like:

```
SELECT
    `outer`.`model`,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM
            `cars` AS `inner`
        WHERE
            `inner`.`model` = `outer`.`model` AND
            `inner`.`id` NOT IN(
                SELECT `carid`
                FROM `reservations`
                WHERE `date` = '2013-03-07'
            )
        GROUP BY `inner`.`model`
    ) AS `count`
FROM cars AS `outer`
GROUP BY `outer`.`model`;
```

then you would get results like:

```
+----------+-------+
| model    | count |
+----------+-------+
| explorer |     2 |
| viper    |  NULL |
+----------+-------+
```

If you then needed the NULL value to come back as a 0, you could use COALESCE, as Liv mentioned previously.

It's *not* pretty, and I'm sure it could be done a *much* cleaner way, but it does work.

Answer (score -1):

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406647/mysql-query-how-to-return-placeholder-value-instead-of-null-if-no-entry-found) asked here that might get you headed in the right direction. Check out the [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function.

The built-in function `COALESCE()` returns the first not-null value in its arguments. This lets you structure queries like `SELECT COALSECE(foo, 'bar') [...]` such that the result will be the value in column 'foo' if it is not null, or the value 'bar' if it is.